# What would you prefer using the sort() method or the aggregation $sort in MongoDb and Why?

Tags: database, mongodb, sorting, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have been browsing over the internet for quite few hours now and didn't came to a satisfactory answer for why one is better over another. If this is situation dependent than what are the situations to use one over the other.It would be great if you could provide me a solution on this with example if there can be one. I understand that since the aggregation operators came later so probably they are the better one, but i have still seen people using the find()+sort() method.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't think of this as an issue of "which method is better?", but "what kind of query do I need to perform?"

The MongoDB aggregation pipeline exists to handle a different set of problems than a simple `.find()` query. Specifically, aggregation is meant to allow processing of data on the database end in order to reduce the workload on the application server. For example, you can use aggregation to generate a numerical analysis on all of the documents in a collection.

If all you want to do is retrieve some documents in sorted order, use `find()` and `sort()`. If you want to perform a lot of processing on the data before retrieving the results, then use aggregation with a `$sort` stage.